# Se l'è/n'è o se le è/ne è?

Tags: verbs, grammar, pronouns, orthography, particles

Da quello che so i clitici plurali non si elidono.
Quindi se possiamo dire indifferentemente "l'ho vista" o "la ho vista", non possiamo fare altrettanto col plurale, quindi solo "le ho viste".

Mi chiedevo: nel caso l'ausiliare sia il verbo essere alla terza persona singolare o plurale, quindi "era/erano", vale lo stesso discorso?

Mi spiego:
"Se la è presa", "se l'è presa", certamente anche "se le è prese", ma si potrebbe dire "se l'è prese"?

Lo stesso dubbio riguarda il cliticl "ne":
"Se ne è mangiata una", "se n'è mangiata una", "se ne è mangiate due" ma "se n'è mangiate due"?

Answer (score 2):

Solitamente, *le* non può essere eliso in *l'* ma *ne* può essere eliso in *n'*.

Il motivo è che *l'* si usa già per i singolari *la* e *lo*, mentre *ne* è invariabile.

Come spesso accade, sicuramente puoi trovare anche la forma "sbagliata" in un sacco di libri, perché tutto sommato è abbastanza logica e si capisce. Inoltre, in passato si usava elidere anche *le* (tipico esempio poetico: *l'acque*, *l'armi*), oggi suona antiquato.

Normale:

- Se le è prese.
- Se n'è prese due.

Strano:

- Se l'è prese.

Comment: Sarà pure “strano”, ma *se l'è prese* si sente eccome.

Comment: Si sente soprattutto perché sono due E affiancate e non è facile distinguerlo nella pronuncia. _L'ha mangiate_ infatti si sente molto meno. Ma senz'altro è possibile dirlo, perciò ho preferito indicarlo come normale/strano piuttosto che come giusto/sbagliato.

Comment: @Mauro Vanetti: in buona sostanza, "l'è" è possibile usarlo se si decide di elidere "lo è/ la è", mentre farlo per elidere " le è" sarebbe antiquato. Con "ne è" è del tutto facoltativo anche se si parli di plurale e singolare: 1) se ne è/n'è mangiata una. 2.) Se n'è/ ne è mangiate due. È giusto?

Comment: Giusto secondo me.

Comment: @MauroVanetti: avrei altre due domande. Il pronome "ne", come riportato in varie trattatazione dell'argomento da treccani, può effettivamente essere eliso, però mi chiedevi se anche in casi "ne ho parlato" o "ne ammiro il coraggio" sia possibile. La seconda domanda riguarda "le" e "gli" ("le" non inteso come articolo plurale o pronome atono di oggetto), ovvero se sia possibile eludere: "l'è piaciuto/gl'è piaciuto" "L'ho risposto/ gl'ho risposto". Grazie e buona serata

Comment: @Maxim mi era sfuggita questa ulteriore domanda, scusami. In effetti è un bel quesito. Sicuramente non si può elidere _le_ neppure quando significa _a lei_, mentre _gli_ (in entrambi i significati) si può al massimo elidere solo di fronte a una parola in _i-_ e pure questo è antiquato (_gl'italiani_, _gl'interessa_). Mi sa che anche per quanto riguarda _ne_ l'elisione si usa soprattutto davanti al verbo _essere_ (_se n'è_, _se n'erano_), suona molto insolito davanti al verbo _avere_ (_n'ha parlato_), suona sbagliato altrimenti (_n'esistono_, _n'utilizzo_): credo sia solo perché non si capisce.